# Intersection of an arbitrary number of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need a function which takes an array of arrays as its argument, then returns the intersection of all the subarrays. How could I improve the following code, if at all?

```
class Array
  def grand_intersection
    if self.length > 1
      filters = self[1..-1]
      filters.reduce(self[0]) {|start, filter| start & filter}
    else
      self
    end
  end
end
```

P.S. I'm not too concerned about handling arrays whose content won't respond to #& -- the method won't be exposed to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Array
  def grand_intersection
    self.reduce :&
  end
end

[[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4], [1,2,4,5]].grand_intersection
  #=> [2, 4]
```

Comment: I was aware that that works with a lot of primitive arithmetic operations, I should have guessed that `&` allows the same syntactic sugar. When is the leading ampersand (as in the other excellent answer) required, and when not? i.e., why can I write `(:+)` but have to write `(&:to_s)` ?

Comment: There are four forms of the method [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`). Two take a symbol as an argument.

Comment: No, I mean what's the difference between `Enumerable.reduce(&:some_method)` and `Enumerable.reduce(:some_method)` without the ampersand? If your answer is meant to address that, I guess I don't understand how the `&` in that context represents a symbol (?)

Comment: The second form takes the name of the method used as the combining operation as a `Symbol`. That's a feature of `inject`, that it has been written to take a `Symbol`. `map`, for example, doesn't take one. The first form is simply the normal Ruby unary prefix ampersand operator which turns a `Proc` into a block (and calls `to_proc` first to convert the argument into a `Proc` if it isn't one).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, @Jörg. pgblu, `:&` is the instance method for computing the intersection of two arrays. `self.reduce &:&` could be written `self.reduce &(:&)`, which is perhaps more clear. The first `&`, the unary operator, converts the method to a proc and then the proc to a block. Here `&` represents two very different things, which may be confusing. If we were instead taking the union, it would be `self.reduce :|` vs `self.reduce &:|`. Both work, but (as with `&`) the former would be more efficient because it doesn't involve the creation and conversion of a proc.

Comment: You asked why you can use `:+` but not `:to_s`. `[1,2,3].reduce(:+)` is equivalent to `[1,2,3].reduce { |memo,e| memo + e }` (i.e., `memo.+(e)`), whereas `[1,2,3].reduce(:to_str)` raises the exception `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) `, as it would expand to `[1,2,3].reduce { |memo,e| memo.to_str(e) }`, but `to_str` does not take an argument.  An example of a string method you could pass to `reduce`:  `['abcdef','a','b','d','f'].reduce(:delete) #=> "ce"`.